# Stack FIFO no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query for FIFO SQL but if an article have not "Sortie" or "Entrée" it doesn't work

Entrée = in, Sortie = out.

```
WITH    Sold
      AS ( SELECT   IT.code ,
                    SUM(IT.quantite)*-1 AS TotalSoldQty
           FROM     dbo.F_Mvtstk It
           WHERE    It.Typ = 'Sortie'
           GROUP BY IT.code
         ),
    Bought
      AS ( SELECT   IT.* ,
                    SUM(IT.quantite) OVER ( PARTITION BY IT.code ORDER BY IT.date ASC ) AS RunningBoughtQty
           FROM     F_Mvtstk IT
           WHERE    IT.Typ = 'Entrée'
         )
SELECT  B.* ,
    S.TotalSoldQty ,
    B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty AS RunningDifferenceQty,        
    IIF(
        B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty < 0, 
        0, 
        B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty
    ) AS  RunningRemainingQty,      
    IIF(
        B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty < 0, 
        0, 
        IIF(
            B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty > B.quantite, 
            B.quantite, 
            B.RunningBoughtQty + S.TotalSoldQty
        )
    ) AS  RemainingQty  
    into essai2
FROM    Bought B
    INNER JOIN Sold S ON B.code = S.code
ORDER BY B.code, B.date, B.id;
```

Test data in the `F_Mvtstk` table

```
   Date   |   Code   |   Designation   |   Quantite   |   Typ   |   Prix
2019-09-15|   A01    |    ARTICLE 01   |      20      | Entrée  |   200
2019-09-16|   A01    |    ARTICLE 01   |      10      | Sortie  |   250
2019-09-17|   A02    |    ARTICLE 02   |      15      | Sortie  |   150
2019-09-17|   A03    |    ARTICLE 03   |      25      | Entrée  |   100
```

If I suppress the `A02` and `A03` then it works.

Can any one help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and describe the logic you want to implement.

Comment: i did it, it's clear

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: @MohammedFETTAH it's not clear. This query has nothing to do with the title - it doesn't show any stack structure in SQL or query that pops something from a stack. It's a query over an unknown table with unknown data. We don't know what the results should look like or what the problem is

Comment: @MohammedFETTAH one would have to guess that the table contains source data from the field names - they don't appear anywhere in the SELECT statement, while *some* of them appear in the CTEs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , my query work but juste for "A01", i want to change it to work for all articles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply want something like this:

```
SELECT code, TotalSoldQty, TotalBought,
       SUM(TotalBought) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as runningBought,
       SUM(TotalSold) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as runningSold,
       (SUM(TotalBought) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) +
        SUM(TotalSold) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as runningSold
       ) as net
FROM (SELECT IT.code, IT.date,
             SUM(CASE WHEN It.Typ = 'Sortie' THEN IT.quantite)*-1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalSoldQty,
             SUM(CASE WHEN It.Typ = 'Entrée' THEN IT.quantite) ELSE 0 END) AS TotalBought
      FROM dbo.F_Mvtstk It
      GROUP BY IT.code, IT.date
     ) c
```

Comment: it does'nt work, the problem that my query work but juste for "A01", i don't know why ?